# How to open ionic 4 application in debug mode?

Tags: angular, ionic4

I am practicing ionic 4 and I have added ionic4 native calendar to work with calendar. Since I cannot run Cordova in web to debug I want to use emulator. I can run my application in emulator without liverelaod.

```
ionic cordova emulate ios
```

This works fine but when I try to run it in debug mode, it doesn't show any error and my app goes loading and loading in emulator. I have tried following commands.

```
ionic cordova emulate ios -l
ionic cordova emulate ios -lc
ionic cordvoa emulate ios --livereload
```

I can see BUILD is successful and I am seeing following message at the end and nothing after that:

```
[ng] chunk {home-home-module} home-home-module.js, home-home-module.js.map (home-home-module) 22 kB  [rendered]
[ng] chunk {list-list-module} list-list-module.js, list-list-module.js.map (list-list-module) 6.71 kB  [rendered]
[ng] chunk {polyfills} polyfills.js, polyfills.js.map (polyfills) 223 kB [initial] [rendered]
[ng] chunk {runtime} runtime.js, runtime.js.map (runtime) 8.88 kB [entry] [rendered]
[ng] chunk {styles} styles.js, styles.js.map (styles) 66.3 kB[initial] [rendered]
[ng] chunk {vendor} vendor.js, vendor.js.map (vendor) 4.72 MB [initial] [rendered]
[ng] ℹ ｢wdm｣: Compiled successfully.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Safari to see debug logs.

1. Go to Safari, open preferences and in Advanced tab check that **Show Develop menu in menu bar** is activated.
2. On Safari, while your app is running, click on Development in the menu bar, and you will find your **Simulator - Device Name** in which you can select the IP where your Ionic app is running.

That will open a developer console where you will, luckily, see what's wrong on your app.

Answer (score 0):

open chrome--->

right click --->

inspect--->

then select

Remote device

[image]

select more tools